# Cannot see work item workflow using Visual Studio 2012 and TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-power-tools

I have an issue, we recently upgraded from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012. Before, in TFS 2010, I was able to use Visual Studio 2010 and VS Power Tools 2010 to be able to open and modify Work Item Types.

Now, after the upgrade, I cannot edit work item types even when using Visual Studio 2012 Team Explorer and Power Tools 2012. Whenever I open the work item to be modified, I get this single xml line:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><workItemType dslVersion="3.0.0.0" Name="Bug" source="http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/tfsserver/TFS Sandbox/Bug" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dsltools/WITDesigner" />`

Anyone know how I can get the workflow or fields to appear?

Currently using TFS 2012 Team Explorer with TFS 2012 Power Tools.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using VS2012 and Powertools 2012 with the latest updates? Unfortunately I can't reproduce the problem, because for me it works like it does in VS2010 with PowerTools 2010. I expect you go "Tools-> Process Editor -> Work Item Types-> Open WIT from Server", right?

Comment: Yes, I am using VS2012 with PowerTools 2012 latest. However, I found a solution for it. I am not sure what happened but it seems something happened during the installation process, as uninstalling all of the 2012 suite (both VS and Powertools) and then reinstalling it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for it. I am not sure what happened but it seems something happened during the installation process, as uninstalling all of the 2012 suite (both VS and Powertools) and then reinstalling it fixed it.